# BERT tokenizer & model download

Tags: python, github, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I`m beginner.. I'm working with Bert. However, due to the security of the company network, the following code does not receive the bert model directly.

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-cased', do_lower_case=False)
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-cased", num_labels=2)
```

So I think I have to download these files and enter the location manually.
But I'm new to this, and I'm wondering if it's simple to download a format like .py from github and put it in a location.

I'm currently using the bert model implemented by hugging face's pytorch, and the address of the source file I found is:

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers

Please let me know if the method I thought is correct, and if so, what file to get.

Thanks in advance for the comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As described [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/856), what you need to do are download `pre_train` and `configs`, then putting them in the same folder. Every model has a pair of links, you might want to take a look at lib code.

For instance

```
import torch
from transformers import *
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('/Users/yourname/workplace/berts/')
```

with `/Users/yourname/workplace/berts/` refer to your folder

Below are what I found

at `src/transformers/configuration_bert.py` there are a list of models' configs

```
BERT_PRETRAINED_CONFIG_ARCHIVE_MAP = {
    "bert-base-uncased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-uncased-config.json",
    "bert-large-uncased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-large-uncased-config.json",
    "bert-base-cased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-cased-config.json",
    "bert-large-cased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-large-cased-config.json",
    "bert-base-multilingual-uncased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-config.json",
    "bert-base-multilingual-cased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-multilingual-cased-config.json",
    "bert-base-chinese": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-chinese-config.json",
    "bert-base-german-cased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-german-cased-config.json",
    "bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-config.json",
    "bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking-config.json",
    "bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad-config.json",
    "bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad-config.json",
    "bert-base-cased-finetuned-mrpc": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-cased-finetuned-mrpc-config.json",
    "bert-base-german-dbmdz-cased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-german-dbmdz-cased-config.json",
    "bert-base-german-dbmdz-uncased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-german-dbmdz-uncased-config.json",
    "bert-base-japanese": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-config.json",
    "bert-base-japanese-whole-word-masking": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-whole-word-masking-config.json",
    "bert-base-japanese-char": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-char-config.json",
    "bert-base-japanese-char-whole-word-masking": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-char-whole-word-masking-config.json",
    "bert-base-finnish-cased-v1": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1/config.json",
    "bert-base-finnish-uncased-v1": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-uncased-v1/config.json",
}
```

and at `src/transformers/modeling_bert.py` there are links to pre_trains

```
BERT_PRETRAINED_MODEL_ARCHIVE_MAP = {
    "bert-base-uncased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-uncased-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-large-uncased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-large-uncased-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-base-cased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-cased-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-large-cased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-large-cased-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-base-multilingual-uncased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-base-multilingual-cased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-multilingual-cased-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-base-chinese": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-chinese-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-base-german-cased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-german-cased-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-base-cased-finetuned-mrpc": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-cased-finetuned-mrpc-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-base-german-dbmdz-cased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-german-dbmdz-cased-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-base-german-dbmdz-uncased": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-german-dbmdz-uncased-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-base-japanese": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-base-japanese-whole-word-masking": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-whole-word-masking-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-base-japanese-char": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-char-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-base-japanese-char-whole-word-masking": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-char-whole-word-masking-pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-base-finnish-cased-v1": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1/pytorch_model.bin",
    "bert-base-finnish-uncased-v1": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-uncased-v1/pytorch_model.bin",
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the first reply! I've seen that issue when I load the model             1. save them in a directory and rename them respectively config.json and pytorch_model.bin                                                                                                                  2. `model = BertModel.from_pretrained('path/to/your/directory')'                                  I used the method of "I downloaded the model of bert-base-multilingual-cased above and it says undefined name."

Comment: after downloading, and moving to your company's folder, during running time, do you have any difficulty?

Comment: I put the file in the same directory as the file in my jupyter notebook and ran it as follows:
'model = BertModel.from_pretrained ('./')'

Can you tell me some examples of code use?

Comment: model = Bert-base-multilingual-cased.from_pretrained('./pytorch_model.bin')  ... like this?? after excuting that code NameError: name 'Bert' is not defined.... sry I`m beginner...

Comment: I see. I added more details, can u check it. I guessed the reason was `Bert-base-multilingual-case`, there is no class has this name

Comment: model = BertModel.from_pretrained('/Users/yourname/workplace/berts/')        
  Should I replace the 'BertModel' name with the model I downloaded in this code?

Comment: I think I'm looking for a way to do it. Thank you so much for the answer.
I'll try it tomorrow. Thank you again!

Comment: depending on what you want. In transformers, the lib provides transforms and fine-tuning on down-stream tasks. These classes are `BertModel`, `BertForPreTraining`, `BertForMaskedLM`, `BertForNextSentencePrediction`, `BertForSequenceClassification`, `BertForTokenClassification`, `BertForQuestionAnswering`

Comment: oh Now I`m understand! Thank you so much!