# Hugginface Bert Tokenizer build from source due to proxy issues

Tags: python, tokenize, huggingface-transformers

I encountered something similar to this: [BERT tokenizer & model download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701981/bert-tokenizer-model-download)

The link above is about downloading the Bert model itself, but I would only like to use the Bert Tokenizer.

Normally I could do it like this:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer
bert_tokenizer_en = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
bert_tokenizer_de=BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-german-cased")
```

But I am running it remotely, so I can't download via the method above. But I do not know which files I need from here: https://huggingface.co/bert-base-uncased/tree/main, so that I could build the tokenizer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to 1) download vocabulary and configuration files (`vocab.txt`, `config.json`), 2) put them into a folder and 3) pass folder's path to `BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(<path>)` function.

Here is the download location of `vocab.txt` for different tokenizer models

```
PRETRAINED_VOCAB_FILES_MAP = {
"vocab_file": {
    "bert-base-uncased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-uncased/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "bert-large-uncased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-large-uncased/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "bert-base-cased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-cased/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "bert-large-cased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-large-cased/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "bert-base-multilingual-uncased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-multilingual-uncased/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "bert-base-multilingual-cased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-multilingual-cased/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "bert-base-chinese": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-chinese/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "bert-base-german-cased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-german-cased/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking": "https://huggingface.co/bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking": "https://huggingface.co/bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad": "https://huggingface.co/bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad": "https://huggingface.co/bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "bert-base-cased-finetuned-mrpc": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-cased-finetuned-mrpc/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "bert-base-german-dbmdz-cased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-german-dbmdz-cased/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "bert-base-german-dbmdz-uncased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-german-dbmdz-uncased/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1": "https://huggingface.co/TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-uncased-v1": "https://huggingface.co/TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-uncased-v1/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
    "wietsedv/bert-base-dutch-cased": "https://huggingface.co/wietsedv/bert-base-dutch-cased/resolve/main/vocab.txt",
}
```

Location of `config.json`:

```
BERT_PRETRAINED_CONFIG_ARCHIVE_MAP = {
    "bert-base-uncased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-uncased/resolve/main/config.json",
    "bert-large-uncased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-large-uncased/resolve/main/config.json",
    "bert-base-cased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-cased/resolve/main/config.json",
    "bert-large-cased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-large-cased/resolve/main/config.json",
    "bert-base-multilingual-uncased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-multilingual-uncased/resolve/main/config.json",
    "bert-base-multilingual-cased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-multilingual-cased/resolve/main/config.json",
    "bert-base-chinese": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-chinese/resolve/main/config.json",
    "bert-base-german-cased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-german-cased/resolve/main/config.json",
    "bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking": "https://huggingface.co/bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking/resolve/main/config.json",
    "bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking": "https://huggingface.co/bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking/resolve/main/config.json",
    "bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad": "https://huggingface.co/bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad/resolve/main/config.json",
    "bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad": "https://huggingface.co/bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad/resolve/main/config.json",
    "bert-base-cased-finetuned-mrpc": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-cased-finetuned-mrpc/resolve/main/config.json",
    "bert-base-german-dbmdz-cased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-german-dbmdz-cased/resolve/main/config.json",
    "bert-base-german-dbmdz-uncased": "https://huggingface.co/bert-base-german-dbmdz-uncased/resolve/main/config.json",
    "cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese": "https://huggingface.co/cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese/resolve/main/config.json",
    "cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-whole-word-masking": "https://huggingface.co/cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-whole-word-masking/resolve/main/config.json",
    "cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-char": "https://huggingface.co/cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-char/resolve/main/config.json",
    "cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-char-whole-word-masking": "https://huggingface.co/cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-char-whole-word-masking/resolve/main/config.json",
    "TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1": "https://huggingface.co/TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1/resolve/main/config.json",
    "TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-uncased-v1": "https://huggingface.co/TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-uncased-v1/resolve/main/config.json",
    "wietsedv/bert-base-dutch-cased": "https://huggingface.co/wietsedv/bert-base-dutch-cased/resolve/main/config.json",
    # See all BERT models at https://huggingface.co/models?filter=bert
}
```

Source: Transformers codebase [1](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/models/bert/tokenization_bert.py#L31-L52), [2](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/models/bert/configuration_bert.py#L27-L51)

Steps:

```
mkdir ~/german-tokenizer
cd german-tokenizer
wget https://huggingface.co/bert-base-german-cased/resolve/main/vocab.txt
wget https://huggingface.co/bert-base-german-cased/resolve/main/config.json

python

# Python Runtime:
>> import transformers
>> from transformers import BertTokenizer
>> BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('~/german-tokenizer')
```